# Macbook Pro 13 inch mid 2012 not running two daisy chained thunderbolt displays

Tags: display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I am trying to run two thunderbolt displays with my macbook pro and it will only run one at a time.

I have tried the displays with an older 17 inch model and it runs all three (including the internal screen) fine.

- OS X 10.11.1
- 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5
- 8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3
- Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's that my laptop is on the edge of being powerful enough for both.

I made some space on my hard disk, stopped any applications from opening automatically on login and restarted whilst plugged in to both monitors.

Comment: I understand that this is old post, but didi you manage to have 2x monitor in daisy chain ?